# Using multiprocessing for speeding up IO in python

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have some code that reads several datasets, keyed by (call it) "year", and then does some joining on them. I am trying to speed up the code by parallelizing the "read" portion of the problem. I did so by writing this function:

Now, this code does start several processes in parallel and each of them finishes quickly, but the overall runtime ends up being slower than that of simply doing these reads serially.

What am I doing wrong?

```
def parallelQueueRead():                                                         
  start_time = timeit.default_timer()                                             
  myq = Queue()

  def reader(year, q):                                                            
    loc_start_time = timeit.default_timer()                                        
    print("reading year %s" % (year))                                                                                      
    astore = store(year)                                  
    df = astore.getAllData(TESTSPEC)                                               
    astore.close()                                                                 
    q.put((year, df))                                                              
    print("finished reading year %s ,took: %s" %                                   
      (year, str(timeit.default_timer() - loc_start_time)))

  processes = [Process(target = reader, args = (y, myq)) for y in CHUNKS ]        
  for p in processes:                                                             
    p.start()              

  results = [ myq.get() for p in processes ]                                      
  results = sorted(results, key = lambda x: x[0])     

  print("parallel read took: " + str(timeit.default_timer() - start_time))
```

Output:

```
reading year 2011
reading year 2012
reading year 2013
reading year 2014
reading year 2015
finished reading year 2011 ,took: 1.142295703291893
finished reading year 2014 ,took: 1.2605517469346523
finished reading year 2013 ,took: 1.2637327639386058
finished reading year 2012 ,took: 1.2874943045899272
finished reading year 2015 ,took: 1.7436037007719278
parallel read took: 5.500953913666308
```

Output from another routine that does the same thing serially in just one process:

```
serial read took: 5.3680868614465
```

**Post-script 1**

Just to clarify: the serial version is a simple for-loop:

```
results = [] 
for year in CHUNKS:
    results += [ astore.getAllData(TESTSPEC) ]
```

**Post-script 2**

On reading the documentation, I think the reason the parallel version is slow is due to pickling a large dataset (the result of the reader). The time taken to do this is included in the time reported by each picker (and in addition, the time taken to unpickle the results is included in the overall time).

This is really terrible news for me because it means that multiprocessing is not able to speedup the execution of my code.

Comment: Put a timer around the creation and starting of those worker processes.  This task may just not be long enough to make parallelizing across processes worth the process creation overhead.  Note that your 5 processes cumulatively spent 6.6 seconds working, but overlapped their work such that the elapsed time was only 5.5 seconds.

Comment: What is `astore`? It's hard to tell if its an operation that can be well-parallelized.

Comment: On looking at the documentation a bit, I think the problem is that Queue (or any communication between the processes spawned using multiprocessing, I think), needs the data to be pickled. The added overhead from that makes the parallel version slow. @PaulMcGuire: I think the pickling is included in times of the individual tasks, which is why their aggregate is slower than the serial function.

Comment: @Will: astore is a store of data, the atomic version of what I am reading. In the "serial" version, I read the data in one process (in a for loop) the parallel version is above.

Comment: Seems the bottleneck is not the reading. If you are storing every file on the same disk, you are better off doing the read serially. Unless of course the disk is fast enough to serve multiple processes.

Comment: Did some profiling, it seems the parallel version is much faster without passing everything back to the master process. So you are correct in that it's probably the problem of the Queue, which is based on interprocess communication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the structure of the data in `df` (result of `astore.getAllData(TESTSPEC)`) you could try to use [sharedctypes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.sharedctypes) to store the collected data in the shared memory. Certainly this method is useful mainly for 'POD's - data-only structures without any code or complex objects within.

Also I would move entire dataprocessing to the children and make sure that `astore` is actually capable to work in parallel w/o synchronizing (or at least minimizing sync time) between clients (different processes).

But certainly all these suggestions are based on the 'common sense' - without precise knowledge about your app internals and accurate profiling it'd be hard to say exactly what'd be the best solution for you

Comment: One big lesson for here was that a lot depends on the scenario. A shared memory implementation was only competitive on my laptop, with the files being on its attached SSD. But on a cluster with the files being on an NFS SSD, the parallel implementation can be made to run more than 4x faster than the serial version.